# how to display image in a ListView by Uri

Tags: android, listview

i have a photo Uri and i want to display it in a listView , how can i do it ?
here is my code

```
Uri img = getImgByContactId(Long id);
map.put("imgcontact", ???? img ??????);
map.put("date", "20/2010");
map.put("duration", String.valueOf(duration));
map.put("type", finalTypeImg);

SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem,    R.layout.calllogtemplate,
   new String[] {"num", "name", "imgcontact", "date", "duration", "type"}, 
   new int[] {R.id.num, R.id.name, R.id.imgcontact, R.id.date, R.id.duration, R.id.typecall});

ListView maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
maListViewPerso.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

thanks

Comment: Write your own adapter that extends ArrayAdapter, then in getView() deal with the image yourself and set it to an imageview using your uri.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this adapter, should save you a few hours of work: https://github.com/tbiehn/Android-Adapter-Image-Loader

Comment: @user1162759 If either answer helped you, please consider accepting it [by pushing the checkmark next to it]. SO's reputation system depends on you doing so :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Drawable setImageUri(uri) then setDrawable in your ImageView. Use ImageView in your ViewHolder within getView() of your adapter. Read about BaseAdapter too. Hope it helps abit.
Cheers